# do not hide bootstrap tooltip while user focus on tooltip content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented bootstrap tooltip using hover in my application. When user move to the tooltip content  tooltip is hiding. Can anybody suggest  should not hide tooltip while user focusing on tooltip content

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>
```

If user focus or move tooltip content it is hiding . How to avoid this

Thanks

Comment: add your code and what you have tried so far

Comment: Add a code piece for help people understand your code and show where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, the desired behaviour of the tooltip is inverted. So that when you are not hovering on the tooltip it is actually showing? Is that what you are seeing?

I have created a JSFiddle example here... https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/4zng2hmL/6/

```
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>
```

It may be best to share your code, so we can understand the issue better and help you more effectively.

Edit:
Incase you haven't referenced the documentation for bootstrap tooltips, here is a link... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/